# Class allocation in Bash

Tags: bash

I have some sort of a puzzle that i`m stuck in. 
The issue is as fallow:
I have a list "A" of numbers from 103 to 17431. 
Example:

```
103
104
105
......
17430
17431
```

Now parts of this list will come inside dome Classes. For an example

```
Class 0

104
156
1114
11456

Class 1

1313
17431

etc
```

The same number from list A is unique in his list and in the class. There are no 2 classes contains same number from list A.
I need to output a list B in csv format with the first column to be the class and the second column to be the correspondent number from list A.

The most obvious method is to make an set of "if/then/else/else if" loops for each entry from list A , but its just not efficient. 
Can somebody help me with a more intelligent solution? 
Thank you.

Comment: "Now parts of this list" - what does that mean?  Is this the same file? Can you post some more example of input file and sample output file you are expecting?

Comment: How do you use list "A"? It seems like you're just reformatting the second input (that's what the currently posted answer does).

Comment: This is exactly what I`m trying to do, to reformat the second output by adding some extra parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in Perl?

```
$ cat foo.txt
Class 0

104
156
1114
11456

Class 1

1313
17431

$ perl -nle '$class = $1 if /^Class (\d+)$/; print "$class,$_" if /^\d+$/' foo.txt
0,104
0,156
0,1114
0,11456
1,1313
1,17431
```

Comment: dose the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Great, if you could accept the answer, I could do with the point :-)